# Spring EL (SpEL) to replace placeholders from properties file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I am using `Spring Boot and SpEL (Expression Language)`. I am want to create **placeholder** in message.properties file so that value can be replace and send to UI.

**message.properties**

```
not.found={0} not found
```

Code:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteEmployee(String employeeId) {
    int deletedCnt = employeeRepository.deleteEmployee(Integer.valueOf(employeeId));
    if(deletedCnt == 0 )
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(env.getProperty("not.found"));
}
```

Here I want to show EmployeeId (Say 123) is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value located under your `not.found` property is nothing more than `String`, so you can perform any operations on that String.
Eg.

```
not.found = Employee with id %s not found
```

And process this message in your service however you desire.

```
throw new ResourceNotFoundException(String.format(env.getProperty("not.found"), employeeId));
```

Moreover you can access other properties and environment variables in your config.

```
default.message = Exception occurred:
not.found = ${default.message} ${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}
```